# R: getting length of a subset within ddply

Tags: r

so I have a data set with the following columns: test_group, person_id, gross, purchases. This is essentially a list of people, how much they've spent, how many times they've purchased, and what group they are in.

I'm using the following ddply code to get some summary statistics:

```
mean_rpu <- ddply(data, .(test_group), summarise, total_rpu=sum(gross),
    total_users=length(person_id), total_purchasers=length(subset(data,  
    purchases > 0)$person_id), mean_rpu=mean(gross), sd_rpu=sd(gross))
```

The problem I'm running into is with the "total_purchasers" summary. I'm trying to get a count of people who are purchasers within each test_group. The current code only displays the total_purchasers in the entire dataset, not repsective of the test_group factor. Any optimizations I can do with this?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without a reproducible example its hard to say for sure, but perhaps you wanted this:

```
total_purchasers=length(person_id[purchases>0])
```

Comment: @user1062293 you need to accept the answer if it worked out for you